# Mark key-value class options as used

Tags: koma-script, documentclass-writing, class-options, kvoptions

I have written a wrapper for the `scrartcl` class in the following way:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycls}[2012/08/23]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption{title}
\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn, openbib, headings=big, DIV=12}{scrartcl}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrartcl}
```

This way I can provide some default arguments for `scrartcl` like `DIV=12` and still override them by passing

```
\documentclass{title=mytitle, subtitle=thesubtitle, DIV=10}
```

The problem I have, is that `srcartcl` marks the other options, e.g., `title=mytitle` as unused

> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s)

which is certainly false. I tried unsetting the options with

```
\DisableKeyvalOptions{mycls}{title}
```

right after `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*`, but that didn't work. How can I mark those options as used?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question completely and my solution is therefore surely wrong.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't doing `\LoadClass[fleqn, openbib, headings=big, DIV=12]{scrartcl}` instead of `\PassOptionsToClass` and `\LoadClassWithOptions` help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a fresh, thorough look at `The LaTeX Companion` (A.4.8) and solved the problem myself.

Despite what I previously assumed, `\PassOptionsToClass` and `\LoadClassWithOptions` do not work together. The whole point of `\LoadClassWithOptions` is passing exactly the same arguments as the current class got. So here switching to `\LoadClass` will now take the default options.

Unfortunately now the user given global options will not overwrite the default ones. Therefore they have to passed manually to the class. Here `kvoptions` provides `\DeclareDefaultOption` as a equivalent to the classic `\DeclareOption*`. All in all the result looks like:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycls}[2012/08/23]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareStringOption{title}
\DeclareStringOption{subtitle}

\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn, openbib, headings=big, DIV=12}{scrartcl}

\DeclareDefaultOption{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\LoadClass{scrartcl}
```

So whenever `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*` sees an unknown option, like `DIV=10`, it passes it along to `scrartcl`, overwriting any default value in the process. That's why `\PassOptionsToClass` had to be moved in front of it.

Comment: As far as the options you pass to `scrartcl` does not depend on the global ones, this shall work. But you should at least define the `draft` option for your class, something like `\DeclareVoidOption{draft}{\overfullrule5\p@}`.

Comment: @tohecz: That is not necessary. Because of my use of `\DeclareDefaultOption`, all those global options (like `draft`) that I'm not handling myself, are passed on to `scrartcl`.

Comment: Oh ok, one learns all the time, even after he's written two sort-of complex classes himself...