# Base a class on another class

Tags: documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining a wrapper class for a set of document classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/defining-a-wrapper-class-for-a-set-of-document-classes)

When writing a new class (say, `journal`), how can I base it on an existing class (say, `scrbook`)?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/defining-a-wrapper-class-for-a-set-of-document-classes

Comment: Thanks @lockstep, this is pretty much what I would like to achieve indeed, but this question didn't show up when searching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *LaTeX Companion* does explain this in more detail, but here is what you basically have to do in your `journal.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{journal}[2012/09/13]

\LoadClass{scrbook}

...
```

You need to be careful when dealing with class options. I discussed this issue when using the `kvoptions` key-value package in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68475/15616. But there are also native LaTeX commands `\DeclareOption`, `\DeclareOption*` and `\ProcessOptions*`.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the command `\LoadClass` there's a command `\PassOptionsToClass{<options-list>}{<class-name>}` that can be used before `\LoadClass{<class-name>}`. This is a simple beginning of your class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2012/09/13 v0.1 My Class]

\PassOptionsToPackage{patch}{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\DeclareBoolOption{draft}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifmyclass@draft
  \LoadClass[draft]{article}
\else
  \LoadClass{article}
\fi
```

If you want all options user gives to `myclass` to be passed to `article`, you can used `\LoadClassWithOptions{article}`. However, this can have some drawbacks and I'm not sure it is always a good idea.

Comment: Please see the [answer I linked to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68475/15616), for the correct way of passing options on in this case (with kvoptions).